# Fail to install SASS using NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lFPk.png)

I'm trying to install SASS on my machine using NPM, but I'm getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the console as `sudo` (i see you are using LINUX or MAC), which are both UNIX-based systems or `Run as administrator` in windows.

If you take a look at the error you are getting it says `permission denied` and that you should try to run that as administrator/root.